# Не сохраняет xlsx в PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Я использую библиотеку PHPExcel. Вот так на linux ubuntu я пытаюсь сохранить:

```
$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('./results.xlsx');
```

Не происходит сохранение файла, а если на windows, то работает:

```
$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('./results.xlsx');
```

На linux работает правда стили работают только на linux при открытии файла на windows стили не работают:

```
$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('./results.xlsx');
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: а если попробовать $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

Comment: На линуксе не работает, только Excel5 так работает тоже. Я проверял.

Answer (score 1):

У меня возникала похожая проблема. Есть большой файл с классом. В начале этого файла подключаются различные библиотеки в том числе PHPExcel. Сам файл находится в определенном пространестве имен. В одной из функций этого класса происходит генерация XLSX файла. Написал функцию генерации. Вне класса она работала нормально, но при использовании в классе получался битый XLSX файл. Проблему получилось решить убрав из конца файла с классом закрывающий `?>`

Comment: А в чём вы находите схожесть вашей проблемы и описаной в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже новичёк в пхп, но мне кажется, что "\" в первой строке лишняя.

$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);   ----->

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);

Comment: Подозреваю что `\\` используется для вызова namespace